# Could not run PHP files inside the crontab for Ubuntu server

Tags: php, mongodb, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I need to run two php file in each 2 sec using cronjob but it's not working. My file path is below:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /var/www/html/abcd.com/public_html/beta/cron_user.php>dev/nul 2>&1
```

The above file I have placed inside crontab and I need to run this file at each 2 sec. In this file I have a database operation which is given below:

```
$dbobj = new DBConnection();
$db = $dbobj->connectFront();
$cnt =0;
$count=1;
$db->kf_test_cron->insert(array("key"=>"hello"));
```

I need at each 2 sec value will push into `kf_test_cron` collections. But this is not working as expected. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Comment: Finding out what's not working as expected is MORE difficult than writing a helpful answer to your problem.

Comment: @user3606329 : I mean i can not insert value inside collections.

Comment: What does "not working as expected" mean?  What happens?  Regarding the timing, the first field in the cron job is minutes, not seconds.  So your job will run every 2 minutes.